# Downloading software from websites that lacks a padlock

Tags: websites

Some websites don't have a [padlock symbol](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-do-i-tell-if-my-connection-is-secure) to the left of the URL in Firefox.
The only symbol is the letter "i" in the center of a circle - colored in gray.

How do I know whether it's safe to download software from them?

(BTW, even `security.stackexchange.com` doesn't have a padlock.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The padlock is just a visual cue used by the browser to show you that your traffic is being encrypted when sent and received from the server. It represents an **SSL Certificate** but for this answer we can just use the term *padlock*.

The padlock does not make any claims of trustworthiness, it merely shows whether the traffic between your computer and the server is encrypted, that is it cannot be seen (in clear text) by other people sniffing traffic between the two endpoints).

In fact, many times attackers will purchase SSL certificates (*the padlock*) to encrypt traffic to evade Intrusion Detection Systems (IDS) and Intrusion Prevention Systems (IPS), so seeing the padlock should not automatically equal safe content.

**Recommendation**

Instead or relying on the padlock, use reputation based content filtering and pay attention to the domain used in the URI to avoid social engineering / phishing scams directing you to unscrupulous content.

- Examples:

  - `paypal.com != paypa1.com`
  - `google.com != g00gle.com`

**UPDATE**

As noted in the comments below, there are Man in the Middle (MitM) attacks that can fool a victim into thinking they are connecting to a legitimate source ([DNS cache poisoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_spoofing)), as well as subtleties in language character sets ([IDN homograph attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDN_homograph_attack)) that can look like the English (Latin) Character set.
*Credit: @iismathwizard*

Comment: Even looking at the name and checking yourself doesn't assure you of anything. There are still IDN homograph attacks that avoid this.

Comment: @iismathwizard Given the OPs level of understanding, surely you can understand how this information puts him in a better position than he was before.

Comment: Absolutely, I'm just mentioning that it's not the end-all-be-all and it's more a "rule of thumb".

Comment: @iismathwizard, understood and it's valid to note, just a little above the consumer's level in this particular situation.

Comment: To be fair, he's not the only person that this question or answer is going to cater to. Other people might find this question through google and read it in the future. It's not a bad idea to add a little more information for those in the future that might be a more advanced.

Comment: @iismathwizard updated the answer

Comment: hm... very interesting about **DNS cache poisoning** and **homograph**... We should be aware of everything..

Answer (score 0):

The padlock is to indicate that the page you are on is secured with SSL, using the HTTPS protocol.

Being on a secured connection in no way implies that what is there is reliable or not.  The only difference between the two is that sending information through an unsecured connection can be intercepted by malicious third parties.

As for what you should or shouldn't download, use your best judgment based on the quality of the site and make sure to have an up to date antivirus running on your computer.